# check not existing records in mysql table out of searching records

Tags: mysql

I'm working on one mysql query requirement.

HAving one table Details with following details

```
Id  Emails

1   abc@mail.com
2   bbb@mail.com
3   ccc@mail.com
4   ddd@mail.com
5   eee@mail.com
6   fff@mail.com
7   ggg@mail.com
8   hhh@mail.com
9   iii@mail.com
10  jjj@mail.com
```

Its a very huge table, but am showing you as an example table

Sometimes I get a list of emails to check existence of them in Details table.

Let say If I get email id's like abc@mail.com, bbb@mail.com and zzz@mail.com

I want the list of email that dont exist in output out of the three emails given in requirement to check i.e zzz@mail.com !!

What would be the query to check what email id's not exist in the table details out of the given requirement (abc@mail.com, bbb@mail.com and zzz@mail.com)

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Are you just asking what `where` criteria to apply?  What have you tried?  Perhaps look into using `not in`...

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, updated the question, now I hope its cleared with the complexity am looking to be solved !! :)

Comment: It was always clear what you wanted. _You wanted someone to write your code for you_ ___But we dont work from specifications, not even good ones___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the non-existence of things is tricky in an SQL result, because in order to appear in a result set, an item must exist somewhere (either as a value in a column, or as a hard-coded value in the query, or as a value *derived* from one of those).  Since you want to get a result set containing the values that *don't* appear in a table, you'll need to do more than one query.  Fortunately, you can nest them.

```
select addr, Emails from 
  (select 'abc@mail.com' as addr 
   union select 'bbb@mail.com' as addr
   union select 'zzz@mail.com' as addr) as fd
left outer join Details on Details.Emails = fd.addr
having Emails IS NULL
```

We do a bunch of `union`-ed `select`s to build a "table" of the searched-for values.  We then join that table to the `Details` table, and keep only the rows where the join *fails* (The joined table is `NULL`).

[See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2bc3/1)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is:

```
SELECT * FROM {yourTable} WHERE eMails="the email address"
```

Or for multiple:

```
SELECT * FROM {yourTable} 
WHERE eMails IN ({comma separated and quoted list of email addresses})
```

If this returns zero records, the e-mail address does not exists.

One limitation: Depending on your DBMS setup the `IN` statement is limited to a maximum number of values. Take care you do not go above that else you will get an error or no valid response.

If you use really long list, then insert them in a temporary table and join that table with your base table to get the un-used list.

Comment: this logic I know but I want the list of email that dont exist in output out of the three emails given in requirement to check i.e zzz@mail.com !!

Comment: You will have to add either a check loop or use the temporary table solution. With a temporary table you can use a `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE temptable.value IS NOT NULL` to keep the values which don't exist.

Comment: Can you not just use `NOT IN ({comma separated and quoted list of email addresses})`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I can't Riggs, because that will return me all email present in details table but not in the requirement mails to check !!

Comment: Oh now I understand the question

Comment: What's your suggestion @RiggsFolly ? Any way to do it in single query ?